# plotting with bessel functions in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run this code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special as spl 

def minf(x):
    return x[0]**2 + (x[1]-1.)**2

sol = minimize(minf, [1,2])
x = np.linspace(0,10,5000)
plt.plot(x, spl.jv(3,x), '-', sol.x, -sol.fun, 'o')
```

I get this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

How to correctly specify the plot statement?

My objective is to plot a landscape of inputs and function values. In this case, a two dimensional set of inputs. I want to know how I can use linspace, the bessel function and plot correctly for achieving this.

I expect a plot like this, with also the optimal point marked:

https://sites.google.com/site/haripkannan/Home/plot_pdqp.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not quite right with the output from `minimize`. It is unclear what you are trying to do with it. Look at the output of `sol`, how is this supposed to be plotted?

```
print sol.x, sol.fun
> [ -7.45132580e-09   9.99999993e-01] 1.1104451202e-16
```

Nevertheless, plotting your Bessel function is simple:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,500)
y = spl.jv(3,x)
plt.plot(x, y, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please, check my edits at the end of the question. I have made my objective clear.

Comment: It still is unclear, what is a "a two dimensional set of inputs" when you have the bessel function(x,y) + two extra points? Like I said, I think something is wrong with your minimize - what exactly did you expect?